# Problems deploying to iOS adHoc XE4

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

Getting error

Unable to install package (e8008015) when trying to install my iPad app ad hoc. It runs OK when I use debug however I don't seem to be able to read/write files.

I am having this problem even after making sure that Ad-Hoc in Project manager for all configurations iOS device Provisioning. I think I have set up my Mobile provisioning profile with the information from XCode correctly. Can anyone please help with this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly is your problem? Please provide more details.